# How can I save a range object (from getSelection) so that I can reproduce it on a different page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to make a web app which allows the user to select some text on a page, and then with the click of another button highlight it. When the user goes back to the page, I want the highlight to show up in the same spot as well.

So I've gotten as far as:

```
var selectedRange = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
highlightRange(selectedRange);
```

Where highlightRange is a function that highlights the range. This works so far.

The problem is, I need a way to save the selectedRange into a database so that it can be fetched again later. After that, I need to re-create the range from this data and highlight it again. I've found this method:

```
document.createRange();
```

From this page here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range

But I'm not really sure how I can make this work

**UPDATE:**

I know I'll need to re-create the range from scratch afterwards. And to do that I will use something like this:

```
var range = document.createRange();

range.setStart(startNode,startOffset);
range.setEnd(endNode,endOffset);
```

I can easily store startOffset and endOffset because those are just numbers. But startNode and endNode are node objects. I don't know how to store this in a database?

More specifically, I need to store the *reference* to the node in a database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have updated my post with more detail, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving 5 pieces of information from the range into the database:

```
var saveNode = range.startContainer;

var startOffset = range.startOffset;  // where the range starts
var endOffset = range.endOffset;      // where the range ends

var nodeData = saveNode.data;                       // the actual selected text
var nodeHTML = saveNode.parentElement.innerHTML;    // parent element innerHTML
var nodeTagName = saveNode.parentElement.tagName;   // parent element tag name
```

And then to build the range from the database, I have this function:

```
function buildRange(startOffset, endOffset, nodeData, nodeHTML, nodeTagName){
    var cDoc = document.getElementById('content-frame').contentDocument;
    var tagList = cDoc.getElementsByTagName(nodeTagName);
    
    // find the parent element with the same innerHTML
    for (var i = 0; i < tagList.length; i++) {
        if (tagList[i].innerHTML == nodeHTML) {
            var foundEle = tagList[i];
        }
    }

    // find the node within the element by comparing node data
    var nodeList = foundEle.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        if (nodeList[i].data == nodeData) {
            var foundNode = nodeList[i];
        }
    }

    // create the range
    var range = cDoc.createRange();

    range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
    range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
    return range;
}
```

From there, I can just use my `highlightRange` function again to highlight the text.

## Update 2022-01

Didn't know this was actually still being used. Thought I might as well give two cents about the two for loops and how we can improve them with modern syntax:

```
const foundEle = tagList.find(x => x.innerHTML === nodeHTML);
const foundNode = nodeList.find(x => x.data === nodeData);
```

Comment: @Amitraj What about this prevents it from being cross-platform?

Comment: Where are you getting startNode and endNote vars from?  You are also putting foundNode and foundEle out of scope of range.

Comment: I'm getting that `startNode` and `endNode` in the `buildRange()` function are undefined. Am I missing something?

Comment: for anyone reading through this answer, this is working and the `startNode` and `endNode` is the `foundNode` variable.

Comment: Note this does not work if the selection spans across different nodes (since above code assumes startNode and endNode are the same)

Answer (score 2):

run the following script  when user select texts

```
let sel = window.getSelection();
let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
let startNode = range.startContainer;
let endNode = range.endContainer;

if (startNode.nodeType == 3) {
  var startIsText = true;
  var startFlag = startNode.parentNode;
  startNode = startNode.nodeValue;
} else {
  var startIsText = false;
  var startFlag = startNode;
}
if (endNode.nodeType == 3) {
  var endIsText = true;
  var endFlag = endNode.parentNode;
  endNode = endNode.nodeValue;
} else {
  var endIsText = false;
  var endFlag = endNode;
}

let startOffset = range.startOffset; 
let endOffset = range.endOffset; 

let startTagName = startFlag.nodeName;
let startHTML = startFlag.innerHTML;

let endTagName = endFlag.nodeName;
let endHTML = endFlag.innerHTML;

//you can store this in database and use it
let rInfo = {
  startNode: startNode,
  startOffset: startOffset,
  startIsText: startIsText,
  startTagName: startTagName,
  startHTML: startHTML,

  endNode: endNode,
  endOffset: endOffset,
  endIsText: endIsText,
  endTagName: endTagName,
  endHTML: endHTML
};
window.localStorage.setItem("r", JSON.stringify(rInfo));
```

then use the following scripts when user go back to the page

```
function findEle(tagName, innerHTML) {
  let list = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].innerHTML == innerHTML) {
      return list[i];
    }
  }
}

function show(startNode,startIsText,startOffset,
          endNode,endIsText,endOffset,sP,eP) {
  var s, e;
  if (startIsText) {
    let childs = sP.childNodes;
    console.log(childs);
    for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
      console.log(childs[i].nodeValue);
      console.log(startNode);
      if (childs[i].nodeType == 3 && childs[i].nodeValue == startNode)
        s = childs[i];
      console.log(s);
    }
  } else {
    s = startNode;
  }
  if (endIsText) {
    let childs = eP.childNodes;
    console.log(childs);
    for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
      if (childs[i].nodeType == 3 && childs[i].nodeValue == endNode)
        e = childs[i];
      console.log(e);
    }
  } else {
    e = endNode;
  }
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(s, startOffset);
  range.setEnd(e, endOffset);

  let sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

function use(obj) {
  let sP = findEle(obj.startTagName, obj.startHTML);
  let eP = findEle(obj.endTagName, obj.endHTML);
  show(
    obj.startNode,
    obj.startIsText,
    obj.startOffset,
    obj.endNode,
    obj.endIsText,
    obj.endOffset,
    sP,
    eP
  );
}
let a = window.localStorage.getItem("r");
use(JSON.parse(a));
```